# landscape in pagesetup cannot be chosen in notepad

Tags: notepad

I cannot choose landscape option in notepad. it is not enable. how can I enable it?

[image]

[image: here it is disabled]

Comment: What OS are u using? Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start → Settings → Printers and faxes → Right click the printer icon →Click printer preferences → Click the basic tab → In the orientation tab and  change to landscape

Try this?

Comment: I will try it. now I don't have access to that computer. this will enable landscape button?

Comment: It very well should let me know if it doesn't

Comment: I don't have this problem in my own PC but I try your solution in my own computer and by changing it, the default option changed to landscape. I hope this will work for that PC.

Comment: Let me know if It doesn't and I will try something else. If it does not enable the button do a test print and see if it does in fact work

Comment: it works fine :)